# Universal Unit Testing Framework

Tags: unit-testing

I have a universal C++ project for Windows, Mac and Linux. Now, I need to do unit testing, what's the best testing framework or techniques I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[there are lots of c++ testing frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B) can you tell us more about your project's requirements? Personally I use [saru](https://github.com/squishyhumans/saru/wiki/_pages) as its very light weight and easy to use

Comment: No any specific requirement, I am just looking for a solution that I write as least code as possible.

Comment: in that case i would suggest choosing something like buildbot to automate your build/test cycle across the different operating systems and choosing a testing framework that is already integrated with your code repository and buildbot  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation